# p:lineChart - continuous line, without dots

Tags: primefaces, jqplot

how to remove the dots from `p:lineChart` and draw the chart as just the continuous line?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

For others with similar problem, I did:

```
<p:chart type="line" model="#{myController.model}"/>
```

and:

```
LineChartSeries serie = new LineChartSeries();
serie.setShowMarker(false);
```

and worked fine. I'm using PrimeFaces 5.1.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `showMarkers` attribute that isn't working for me (I'm using PrimeFaces 3.4.2) but I found a way to hide them.

It's a bit hacky, I made it working on the showcase, you just need to replace `widget_category` by the widget of your chart. You can even test it online from the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/lineChart.jsf) using a javascript console if your web browser allows it (tested under chromium) :

```
// loop through the series
for (var i = 0; i < widget_category.cfg.series.length; ++i) {
    // Hide markers
    widget_category.cfg.series[i].showMarker = false;
    // I'm not sure you want this when talking about 'continuous line'
    // but you can make your chart smooth this way :
    widget_category.cfg.series[i].rendererOptions = { smooth: true };
}

// Ask a refresh using the modified configuration object
widget_category.refresh(widget_category.cfg);
```